# Setting UISwitch state in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiswitch

I would like to reset the state of a UISwitch in a UIPopoverController from my MainViewController. I assume a simple

```
popoverView.switchName.on = NO;
```

wont do the job (as it doesnt seem to be working). Whats the best way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: I have made a few assumptions in my answer. Let me know if I have missed the point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the container for the content view controller that is shown inside the frame. I assume at some point you are calling [initWithContentViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/initWithContentViewController%3a) 
with a view controller that presents the content and that this view controller has the switchName property.

To access this view controller you can use the [contentViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/contentViewController) property of the UIPopoverController. I imagine it will be something like:

```
// assuming popoverView is a UIPopoverController and that the type of 
// the view contorller you pass to initWithContentViewController is YourViewController
YourViewController * myController = (YourViewController*)popoverView.contentViewController;
myController.switchName.on = NO;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Yes, I am calling initWithContentViewController and yes switchName is a property. I tried what you suggested but unfortunately this doesnt seem to work either. The popoverView.contentViewController.switchName doesnt seem to be a valid structure.

Comment: @erno-simonyi Ah! You will have to cast the contentViewController to your UIViewController sub class (which I have called YourViewController). I have updated my answer with that in mind.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out as soon as I get home.

Comment: Sorry for the delay didn't have much time for this recently.Tried it now and it worked like a charm. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @erno-simonyi No problem. Glad you got it sorted.